# Why is conversion failing when doing a select count?

Tags: sql

When doing a select count, I am getting a conversion failed to a unique identifier.

```
select count (rs.column)
from table1 sw
join table2 sl
on sl.column = sw.column
join table3 sps
on sps.column = sw.column
join table4 ps 
on ps.column = sps.column
join table5 ec
on ec.column = ps.column 
join db.table1 rs
on rs.column = sw.column 
where ec.column in 
( 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of your joins joins a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column to a non-`UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column and that (non-uniqueidentifier) column contains some data that cannot be converted to a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, or your where clause attempts to compare a column that is a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` with a value in your in list that cannot be converted to a  `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`

For example:

```
select * from
  (select newid() as a) a
  inner join (select 'x' as b) b
  on a.a = b.b

or

select * from
  (select newid() as a) a
  where
    a.a in ('x','y')
```

> Msg 8169 Level 16 State 2 Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5ce0d5a3ad87b481a85a74e73495c061